# PDO comma in query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey guys i try to get this query with PDO but not achieved so far , so it might be the comma my problem ( ',' ) what you think? what i just try to do is in a field with decimal number or decimal numbers comma separated subtract one value in that string managing of course the comma (delete from the beginning or end). Also would be useful changing the query if necessary

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET field_to_change = SUBSTR(REPLACE(CONCAT(',' , field_to_change, ','), ':userid', ','), 2, LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', field_to_change, ','), ':userid', ',')) - 2) WHERE field_id = :ownid ";

$conn = New PDO ...

$user_with_comma = ','.$value.','

$sql = conn->prepare($query);
$sql->bindValue(':userid', $user_with_comma , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':ownid', $value2 , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
```

i also try

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET field_to_change = SUBSTR(REPLACE(CONCAT(',' , field_to_change, ','),   ', :userid ,', ','), 2, LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', field_to_change, ','), ', :userid ,', ',')) - 2) WHERE field_id = :ownid ";

  $sql->bindValue(':userid', $value , PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

it always gave me the "number of bound variables does not match number of tokens" error .

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Your troubles are the result of a wrong database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reuse parameter tokens that way. Give the first two separate names and assign them the same value:

```
"UPDATE table SET field_to_change = SUBSTR(REPLACE(CONCAT(',' , field_to_change, ','),   :userid1, ','), 2, LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', field_to_change, ','), :userid2, ',')) - 2) WHERE field_id = :ownid "
```

then:

```
$sql->bindValue(':userid1', $user_with_comma , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':userid2', $user_with_comma , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':ownid', $value2 , PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: And don't wrap your bind arguments in quotes in the SQL query - the bindValue call handles that for your

Comment: @MarkBaker Right, I missed that. They were probably being interpreted as literals.

Comment: Where did you read about reusing parameters tokens? , cause i have reused in other query and it work , is this a bug? BTW the wrapped parameter was the big thing . Thank you @MarkBaker